# Why is my insertion sort slower than library merge sort on (almost) sorted data?

Tags: performance, sorting, haskell

The default `Data.List.sort` [is implemented using merge sort](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#sort). I have a huge list of almost sorted data. I figured using insertion sort would be much more beneficial. This was not the case unfortunately.

Edit: Ok. So with -O2 my algorithm seems twice as faster when writing to /dev/null.

`length . mySort [0..1000000]` takes 18.5 seconds and consumes around 13gb of memory. whereas `length . sort [0..1000000]` takes 1.8 seconds and uses around 1.2 gb. This is more than 10 times as performant. Where did I go wrong? Here's my code

```
mvInsertionSort :: Ord a => Mv.IOVector a -> IO (Mv.IOVector a)
mvInsertionSort mv = do
    forM_ [1 .. Mv.length mv - 1] $ \x -> do
        pivot <- Mv.read mv x
        mvInsertionSort' [x-1, x-2 .. 0] mv pivot
    return mv

-- insertion Sort helper
mvInsertionSort' :: Ord a => [Int] -> Mv.IOVector a -> a -> IO ()
mvInsertionSort' (y:ys) mv pivot = do
    currElem <- Mv.read mv y
    if pivot < currElem
        then do 
                Mv.write mv y pivot 
                Mv.write mv (y+1) currElem 
                mvInsertionSort' ys mv pivot
        else Mv.write mv (y+1) pivot

mvInsertionSort' [] _ _ = return ()
```

Comment: Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)
> Adaptive, i.e., efficient for data sets that are already substantially sorted: the time complexity is O(nk) when each element in the input is no more than k places away from its sorted position

So if an element thats supposed to be last is first in the array, the complexity will be O(n^2) for insertion sort.

Comment: Yes. By that logic, in [0..100000] the value of k is 1, So the current (not worst) time complexity of insertion sort should be 1 * n . Which is n.

Comment: Try making mkInsertionSort’ a foldr or forM, because currently, I believe, the range [x-1, x-2 .. 0] is not fusing into a loop with it.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. There’s no need for mvInsertionSort’ to take a [Int] in the first place. You can just count down manually (which is what a foldr version would do, anyway).

Comment: Can you elaborate "the range [x-1, x-2 .. 0] is not fusing into a loop with it" ? How would I use foldr with with? These are mutable vectors, not lists.

Comment: I don't know haskell, but the linked to merge sort appears to be a natural merge sort that splits up an array or vector into ascending (and descending?) runs, then merges the runs. For nearly sorted data, it only takes a few merge passes. For already sorted data, it detects a single sorted (ascending) run in O(n) time.

Comment: A range [x, y, .. z] is produced by a loop. This loop stores values into a list. You immediately consume this list (the first argument of mkInsertionSort’) in another loop. The list is allocated and wastes resources even when it doesn’t need to exist, because the two loops can be fused into one by looping directly from the starting value to 0. Turning mkInsertionSort’ into a foldr or forM over its first argument (I’m not talking about the vectors) will allow the compiler to notice this and fuse the list into nonexistence, or you can do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following self-contained program, compiled with GHC 8.2.2 using `ghc -O2` runs in a tenth of a second and allocates 176M on the heap.  If you bump it up to `[0..10000000]` instead of `[0..1000000]`, it runs in under a second and allocates 1.8G on the heap.  If I run the big version (10 million) under GHCi after `:set +s`, then I approximately duplicate your results: 12.1 secs and 12.9Gig.  If you're running timing tests under GHCi, don't do that!  GHCi compiles to an unoptimized, interpreted byte code.

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as Mv

mvInsertionSort :: Ord a => Mv.IOVector a -> IO (Mv.IOVector a)
mvInsertionSort mv = do
    forM_ [1 .. Mv.length mv - 1] $ \x -> do
        pivot <- Mv.read mv x
        mvInsertionSort' [x-1, x-2 .. 0] mv pivot
    return mv

-- insertion Sort helper
mvInsertionSort' :: Ord a => [Int] -> Mv.IOVector a -> a -> IO ()
mvInsertionSort' (y:ys) mv pivot = do
    currElem <- Mv.read mv y
    if pivot < currElem
        then do 
                Mv.write mv y pivot 
                Mv.write mv (y+1) currElem 
                mvInsertionSort' ys mv pivot
        else Mv.write mv (y+1) pivot

mvInsertionSort' [] _ _ = return ()

main = do
  let v = V.fromList [0..1000000]  -- one million
  v' <- V.freeze =<< mvInsertionSort =<< V.thaw v
  print $ V.length v'
```

Comment: This seems to be the main problem. However the library sort is still faster. Should I use arrays instead of vectors? I just can't seem to figure out this last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: You could redesign `mvInsertionSort'` so that it just takes the first integer `y` instead of the list `[y,y-1..0]`.  That seems to speed it up by about 35% or so.

Comment: K. A. Buhr. That sped things up, but it still seems 25% slower than the library sort.

Comment: I have removed creation of all loops and used counters instead. Still similar performance.

Comment: With both in -O2, my algorithm seems twice as faster. I can't seem to tag you.

Answer (score 0):

Because the complexity of `merge/quick` sort is `O(n * log(n))` as opposed to `O(n*n)` of `insertion` sort.

Comment: Insertion sort is not supposed to be quadratic on (almost) sorted data though

Comment: I am well aware of that. My list is almost sorted. Here's a link. https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms/nearly-sorted-initial-order

Comment: Well, I believe than the implemented sort may include some optimizations for such cases as well.

Comment: It's impossible to know how sorted/unsorted a data set is. Unless it makes an educated guess, scanning some % of the data.

Comment: "some optimizations for such cases" -- As @rjpj1998 hints at, there is no such optimisation. That can be verified through [the source code of `Data.List.sort`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#sort).

Comment: @duplode I see. Other than what you mentioned in the comment, I guess that it also depends on how much 'almost sorted' the data is.

Comment: With respect to that, the OP's test case is with fully sorted data (`[0..1000000]`).